# Idea for securely getting rid of downloaded sensitive information

Tags: windows, usb, temporary-files

So I got assigned a project where a client needs to download some sensitive files from a internal website. The problem is that I need to make sure those files are not recoverable from the computer after they are deleted.

I looked at shredder programs and found some that would work, but then had the following idea which seems much safer.

Let the client download the files to a USB stick, then just delete the USB stick after every download, as they only use it a few days a week this wouldn't be a problem. We also already have nice procedures to deal with sensitive USB sicks already so this would fit nicely into that.

My question then, is this the best way of doing this? Or does anything get saved in Windows? E.x in cache that could reveal the information even if the files get saved on a USB stick?

Comment: Data recovery is possible on flash drives.  It’s more difficult but still possible.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, yeah I know but we got machines that securely erase USB sticks by wiping them so that's not a problem. Just see my question above.

Comment: "does anything get saved in Windows? E.x in cache " No. Nothing to worry about anyway.

Comment: @Moab Thanks! That's what I though but just wanted to confirm it!